# Binding a method to a delegate type DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

**In myUserControl.xaml.cs** I have a bool DependencyProperty called 'IsExtensionValid' whose value is assigned by the following lines:

```
    bool a = TargetFile.Extension.MatchFileMask(FileFilters, true);
    bool b = (FileValidator is null) ? true : FileValidator(TargetFile).Item1;
    IsExtensionValid = (a && b);
```

Where `FileFilters` and `FileValidator` are string and delegate type DependencyProperty's respectively and the delegate type for `FileValidator` is defined as:

```
    public delegate Tuple<bool, string> ExtraValidation(FileInfo fileInfo);
    public delegate Tuple<bool, string> StaticExtraValidation(FileInfo fileInfo, object o);
    // I also tried this static version with corresponding modifications to the function definition and usages (see below) but still couldn't bind
```

**In mainwindow.xaml.cs**, I define a function:

```
    public Tuple<bool, string> ValidateMinFile(FileInfo f) // ExtraValidation delegate
    { return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "File is invalid"); }
    // meaningful test logic removed but principle stands
```

**In mainwindow.xaml** I'm trying to bind `myUserControlInstance.FileValidator = ValidateMinFile` via xaml. I've tried multiple combinations of methods including make `ValidateMinFile` static or not, include as a resource or not, reference as a RelativeSource or not, and several more that I don't remember. My current iteration (translated to contrived-example-land) is:

```
<local:myUserControl x:Name="MinFileControl"
                       FileFilters="Min Files|*.min"
                       FileValidator="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:}}, Path=ValidateMinFile}"/>
```

The real line actually looks like this:

```
<local:FileSelectGroup x:Name="fsgMinFile" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="2"
                       Title="Min file:"
                       FileFilters="Min Files|*.min"
                       PropertyChanged="fsgMinFile_PropertyChanged"
                       FileValidator="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:mainwindow}}, Path=ValidateMinFile}"/>
```

**Edit:** another thing I'd tried was creating a delegate type as a property of mainwindow and setting it to reference a static version of `ValidateMinFile`

```
FileSelectGroup.ExtraValidation ValidateMinFileDelegate = ValidateMinFile;`
```

with `ValidateMinFile` static but when I breakpoint at the line in myUserControl that accesses FileValidator (the one with `bool b = FileValidator...`) FileValidator is null.

---

*How do I bind a function local to a window to a DependencyProperty of a UserControl contained in that window?* or in this particular case: *How do I set `myUserControlInstance.FileValidator = ValidateMinFile` via xaml?*

Comment: I've never heard of a dependency property that's a delegate type. You can't bind it to a method group, certainly. You might be able to give your window a dependency property of the same delegate type, which returns the delegate, and bind that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I did try that and got nowhere (see Edit:) but I may have been doing the binding wrong.

Comment: @Dammer15 I saw your answer - "keep in mind can't bind to private" or something like that just before someone downvoted and it got deleted. Good point. I forgot to set public when I added the delegate property to mainwindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public delegate Tuple<bool, string> ExtraValidation(FileInfo fi);

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region FileValidator Property
    public ExtraValidation FileValidator
    {
        get { return (ExtraValidation)GetValue(FileValidatorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileValidatorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileValidatorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FileValidator), typeof(ExtraValidation), typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, FileValidator_PropertyChanged));
    #endregion FileValidator Property

    protected static void FileValidator_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //  I just put this here for testing: If it's non-null, it'll be called. 
        //  I set a breakpoint in the MainWindow method to detect the call. 
        (d as UserControl1).FileValidator?.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileValidator = ValidateMinFile;
    }

    #region FileValidator Property
    public ExtraValidation FileValidator
    {
        get { return (ExtraValidation)GetValue(FileValidatorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileValidatorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileValidatorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FileValidator), typeof(ExtraValidation), typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion FileValidator Property

    public Tuple<bool, string> ValidateMinFile(FileInfo f) // ExtraValidation delegate
    {
        //  Breakpoint here
        return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "blah");
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <local:UserControl1
        FileValidator="{Binding FileValidator, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        />
```

Works fine.

Comment: Yep, I'd left off the `public` when I created the delegate property. Gah!!! I spent too much time on this and stopped seeing the bleeding obvious. I'll re-test this version and accept if it the light works fine in my office too.

Comment: @Still.Tony That's programming.

Comment: I should have put the nice one-liner c# version in mainwindow's constructor but I want to fully understand the WPF-y way of doing it.

Comment: @Still.Tony I agree. The payoff on mastering bindings is huge.

Comment: It (of course) works and even for the static version. I just wish DependencyProperty declarations weren't such hideous abominations.

Comment: @Still.Tony Yeah, they're pretty miserable. I wrote snippets to create them. The snippets automatically put them in a #region which I can collapse and not have to look at all that barf.

Comment: @Still.Tony Actually, in this particular case, you could do without a dependency property - simple read-only CLR property would suffice. E.g. `public ExtraValidation FileValidator => ValidateMinFile;`. The key is that _WPF_ only supports binding to properties, so you need to expose your method through a property.